# Why does the profile field contact subtype only display individual subtypes but not organisation subtypes?

Tags: profile, contact-types

If you visit here on the CiviCRM Demo site http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/uf/group/field?reset=1&action=browse&gid=16 *(What I did to create this was create a new profile, for the purpose of batch updating via profile, called Subtype and add the field "Contact" "Contact Subtype". )*
Looking at the preview of this field [image: profile preview] 
the only options that are available are subtypes of Individual. Subtypes of Organisation do not show.[image: contact types]

How I can get the Contact Subtype field to display organisation subtypes?

Comment: Jira issue here - https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16787.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this & it seems like as soon as you add a field like 'organisation name' to the profile it switches to an org. Civi doesn't really like you doing 2 different contact types off one form - because it doesn't know what to save them as

Comment: On site in question we added organisation name and legal identifier but still are not seeing a list of subtypes

Comment: Issue here is that the subtypes for Org show fine in Preview, and the Batch Update process works fine if the Orgn chosen in Search results are Orgs - but it fails if they are a sub-type. the scenario is our case was to find contacts of Sub Type X who ALSO should be Sub Type Y

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you've found a bug. You can submit a ticket to http://issues.Civicrm.org but it seems unlikely, given the frequency with which this affects folk, to get fixed by the core team without funding. I'm sure they'd accept a patch to address it though!